# I am executing several fork-joins concurrently,I want one statement skipped in a fork join block if it got executed in any of the other fork joins

Tags: system-verilog, uvm, fork-join

lets say I have a code like this:

```
for (int i=o;i<5;i++) begin
automatic int j=i;
fork
thread(i);
join_none
end
```

suppose thread is like this:
`thread()
    begin
    statement 1;
    statement 2;
    statement 3;
end`

My issue is suppose if statement 2 got executed in the first fork join block then it has to be skipped in the remaining 4 fork join blocks.
Would you be able to tell me a solution on how to implement statement 2.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `j` to your thread instead of `i`.

```
for (int I=0;i<5;i++) begin
   automatic int j=i;
   fork
     thread(j);
   join_none
  end 
task thread (int n);
    statement 1;
    if (n==0) statement 2;
    statement 3;
endtask
```

This does exactly what you asked in the body of your question, but does not match the title. In that case, you would need a semaphore

```
   semaphore flag;
   flag.new(1);
   for (int i=0;i<5;i++) begin
       automatic int j=i;
       fork
         thread(j);
       join_none
      end
      ...
      task thread (int n);
       static bit flag;
            statement 1;
            if (flag.try_get()) statement 2;
            statement 3;
        endtask
```

Comment: I may be wrong here, but don't you need to add some protection like a semaphore or something? Can the statement be preempted?

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for the help.